# Singleton Class in Volley in Android

Tags: android, android-volley

What is the difference between LruCache vs LruBitmapCache?

Right now for Volley image loading and JSON parsing I am using a controller with LruCache.

Comment: `LruBitmapCache extends LruCache`, so there isn't so much a difference, just one is more specific in what it is used for

Comment: for multiple Image which one should I use ? right now I am using a  Lru Cache for simple Image Loading.

Comment: Yes, you already said you have LruCache in the question. I am not sure. What's wrong with what you currently have? Does it not work? Personally, I just use Picasso because it is easier to use than messing with the volley image loader

Comment: Understood ...appreciated